# Could not parse & symbol in url

Tags: node.js, url

I am facing a problem in parsing a URL.

For e.g., let's say the url is http://localhost?query=Tom & Jerry

When I try to fetch query string using

```
const req_query = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}${(req.originalUrl)}`;
const parseURL = require("url");
const uri_parse = parseURL.parse(req_query, true);
console.log(uri_parse.query)
```

I am getting the output as

> { query: "Tom ",   " Jerry": "", }

instead of

> { query: "Tom & Jerry"}

I understand that the & is a special character and is meant to separate queries. Is there anyway I can achieve this? Kindly assist me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

**&** symbol is used to distinguish between different query parameters.
For example :

```
url?firstName=Sethuraman&lastname=Srinivasan
```

after parsing this you'll get :

```
{
    firstName : "Sethuraman",
    lastName : "Srinivasan"
}
```

That's why you are facing the issue.

---

**Solution** is to encode speacial symbols in UTF econding.
To encode it, use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) in your front-end client.

```
const baseURL = "http://localhost";
let ValueToBeEncoded = "Tom & Jerry";
const queryURL = `${baseURL}?query=${encodeURIComponent(ValueToBeEncoded)}`
```

so, Instead the string should be `http://localhost?query=Tom%20%26%20Jerry`